# ReactDOM.createPortal not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-portal

I have some HTML string response from an API that I render on the page using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML". Now this HTML has some empty div tags with a class of "js-lead-in-content" .

I want to show a custom component inside these divs. I am using the react portal for this purpose and I am able to render my custom component inside these empty divs. But I am facing an issue that whenever the parent component updates the HTML string set by "dangerouslySetInnerHTML". The custom components are not added to the empty divs.

```
const ExamDetails = props => {
  const { title, description } = props.content;
  const [showData, setShowData] =  useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowData(true);
  }, [title])

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="font-weight-bold h2"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: title }}
      />
      <div
        className="content-side"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }}
      />
      {showData && ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <h1>gurmeet</h1>,
            document.getElementsByClassName('js-lead-in-content')[0]
          )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ExamDetails;
```

The page on my site has several tabs and each tab has some title and desc. Whenever the tab changes the new data is sent to the above component and it renders it. But only for the first tab which loads I am able to see the portal for the rest of the tabs nothing happens.

Moreover, if I log "document.getElementsByClassName('js-lead-in-content')[0]" it always logs the new DOM node for the active tab.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting showData on first render to true. 
This could be firing createPortal() before the title html has rendered.

```
const ExamDetails = props => {
  const { title, description } = props.content;
  const [showData, setShowData] =  useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
     console.log(title);
    //only set true once this component has received the title prop
    if(title !== undefined && title !== null){ 
       setShowData(true);
    }
  }, [title])

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="font-weight-bold h2"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: title }}
      />
      <div
        className="content-side"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }}
      />
      {showData && ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <h1>gurmeet</h1>,
            document.getElementsByClassName('js-lead-in-content')[0]
          )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ExamDetails;
```